# How can manipulate my list to have the first 10 items as the list in the 50th index for a list with a 100 values

Tags: python

```
scores = []
for i in range (1,101,2):
    scores.append(i)

scores.insert( scores[0] , scores[50])
print(scores)
```

I wanted the 50th value in the list to be subbed in as the first 10 values

Comment: Could you give some sample output?

Comment: what did you do so far?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the first 10 values in `scores` to be the same as `scores[50]`, as if you did this:

```
scores[0] = scores[50]
scores[1] = scores[50]
....
```

You can do this with [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
import itertools

scores[:10] = itertools.repeat(scores[50], 10)
```

This makes an iterator of 10 repeats of `scores[50]` and replaces the first 10 elements of `scores` with that value.